# UIImage with UITapGestureRecognizer in first row of UITableViewController not working properly

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've got a `UITableViewController` subclass that is subclassed by two other classes. In some of the cells of both tables I have an image that the user can click on to perform an action. It all works and I'm happy except that in one of the 2 subclasses the first row of that table has an issue. You can only click the image by clicking to the rightmost edge of the image. If you click in the body of the image it calls the table's didSelectRowAtIndexPath instead.

What boggles me is that it works in the other class for all rows and even in the one it doesn't work for it works in all the other rows where that image shows up. Here's the code I'm using to add the image and gesture recognizer into my cell:

```
        UIImageView *imgparent = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offsetleftmain, 24.0, 14.0, 16.0)];
        imgparent.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"item_open.png"];
        imgparent.tag = ITEMOPENTAG;
        // add listener
        imgparent.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDTapParent = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(loadChildren:)];
        [imgparent addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDTapParent];
        [singleFingerDTapParent release];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgparent];
        [imgparent release];
```

I'm testing in the simulator by the way. I've tried replacing the image with a button but still the problem persists. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Here's the beginnings of the code that is called when the image is clicked. Again, this works but in the case of that one row it only works if you click on the right edge of the image. I've attached a screenshot to illustrate. The first circle indicates where I have to tap in order to get my gesture to be called. The second shows an example in the very same table that allows you to click the entire image. I'm confounded.

```
- (void)loadChildren:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    NSLog(@"loadChildren");

    // get the cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)gestureRecognizer.view.superview.superview;
    UIImageView *imgvw = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:ITEMOPENTAG]; // open arrow
    [imgvw setHidden:YES]; // hide open arrow
    imgvw = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:ITEMCLOSETAG]; // close arrow
    [imgvw setHidden:NO]; // show close arrow

    // get the record for the cell
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Here's the complete `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`. Keep in mind that it's being called from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of 2 other subclasses of this class, each simply passing in an identifier `withType`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                      withType:(NSString *)s_type
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    // if dealing with empty region then show no tasks cell
    if(s_type == @"noTasksCell"){
        cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"noTasksCell"];
        if( cell == nil ) { 
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                     reuseIdentifier:@"noTasksCell"] autorelease];
        }           
        cell.textLabel.text = @"No tasks";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell;
    }

    UILabel *lblMain;
    NSDictionary *o_rec = [self getRecForPath:indexPath];
    NSString *s_cell = @"rowCell";
    BOOL b_parent = NO;
    BOOL b_parentOpen = NO;
    BOOL b_child = NO;
    BOOL b_checked = NO;
    if([self isParent:indexPath]){
        b_parent = YES;
        b_parentOpen = !([o_rec objectForKey:@"b_open"] == nil || [[o_rec objectForKey:@"b_open"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]);
        s_cell = [s_cell stringByAppendingString:@"Parent"];
    }
    if([o_rec objectForKey:@"b_child"] != nil){
        b_child = YES;
        s_cell = [s_cell stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Child%@",[o_rec objectForKey:@"indent"]]];
    }
    if([[o_rec objectForKey:@"checked"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]){
        b_checked = YES;
        s_cell = [s_cell stringByAppendingString:@"isComplete"];
    }
    // add the following to the name:
    //  - project id
    //  - width of table to the name so that rotations will change the cell dequeue names
    // - priority
    s_cell = [s_cell stringByAppendingFormat:
              @"Proj%@Width%dP%@"
              ,[o_rec objectForKey:@"project_id"]
              ,(int)tv.bounds.size.width
              ,[[o_rec objectForKey:@"priority"] stringValue]
              ];

    cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:s_cell];
    if( cell == nil ) { 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:s_cell] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.hidden = YES; // hide the regular text label
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [delegate colorForHexWithAlpha:0xffcc66ff];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        int offsetleftmain = 10;
        if(b_child){
            offsetleftmain += ([[o_rec objectForKey:@"indent"] intValue]-1) * 18;
        }
        if(b_parent){
            // parent arrow
            UIImageView *imgparent = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offsetleftmain, 24.0, 14.0, 16.0)];
            imgparent.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"item_open.png"];
            imgparent.tag = ITEMOPENTAG;
            // add listener
            imgparent.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDTapParent = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(loadChildren:)];
            singleFingerDTapParent.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            singleFingerDTapParent.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
            [imgparent addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDTapParent];
            [singleFingerDTapParent release];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imgparent];
            [imgparent release];
            // close arrow
            UIImageView *imgparent2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offsetleftmain-2, 24.0, 16.0, 14.0)];
            imgparent2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"item_close.png"];
            imgparent2.tag = ITEMCLOSETAG;
            imgparent2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDTapParent2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideChildren:)];
            [imgparent2 addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDTapParent2];
            [singleFingerDTapParent2 release];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imgparent2];
            [imgparent2 release];
        }
        offsetleftmain += 18;
        // checkbox
        UIImageView *imgchk = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offsetleftmain, 20.0, 24.0, 24.0)];
        imgchk.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_empty.png"];
        imgchk.tag = EMPTYCHECKTAG;
        // add listener
        imgchk.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(checkOnItem:)];
        [imgchk addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDTap];
        [singleFingerDTap release];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgchk];
        [imgchk release];
        // checked checkbox
        UIImageView *imgchk2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offsetleftmain, 20.0, 24.0, 24.0)];
        imgchk2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_checked.png"];
        imgchk2.tag = CHECKTAG;
        // add listener
        imgchk2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDTap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(checkOffItem:)];
        [imgchk2 addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDTap2];
        [singleFingerDTap2 release];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgchk2];
        [imgchk2 release];
        offsetleftmain += 28;
        // main label
        lblMain = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offsetleftmain, 22.0, tv.bounds.size.width-offsetleftmain-10, 30.0)];
        lblMain.tag = MAINLABELTAG;
        lblMain.numberOfLines = 4;
        lblMain.font = delegate.font_dflt;
        // change color based on priority
        if (5-[[o_rec objectForKey:@"priority"] intValue] == 1)
            lblMain.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        else if (5-[[o_rec objectForKey:@"priority"] intValue] == 2)
            lblMain.textColor = [delegate colorForHexWithAlpha:H_P2COLOR];
        else if (5-[[o_rec objectForKey:@"priority"] intValue] == 3)
            lblMain.textColor = [delegate colorForHexWithAlpha:H_P3COLOR];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblMain];
        [lblMain release];

        // show action sheet for long press and hold
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *clicknHold = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellClicknHold:)];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:clicknHold];
        [clicknHold release];

    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    // task text
    lblMain = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:MAINLABELTAG];
    lblMain.text = [self formatContent:[o_rec objectForKey:@"content"]];

    CGRect newFrame = lblMain.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = [[o_rec objectForKey:@"height"] floatValue];
    //newFrame.size.height = [[o_rec objectForKey:@"height"] floatValue]+12;
    lblMain.frame = newFrame;
    // set checked status
    [(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:EMPTYCHECKTAG] 
     setHidden:[[o_rec objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue]];
    [(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:CHECKTAG] 
     setHidden:![[o_rec objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue]];
    // show open arrow if dealing with parent cell
    if (b_parent) {
        //NSLog(@"b_parentOpen:%d",b_parentOpen);
        [(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:ITEMOPENTAG] setHidden:b_parentOpen];
        [(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:ITEMCLOSETAG] setHidden:!b_parentOpen];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some more code? Like where you're handeling the tap? Also, have you tried looking at the layers (Debug -> Color Blended Layers) to make sure your imageview is in the right spot?

Comment: Oh my, 14x16px and you are confident it only detects right-edge touches. FYI, not as an answer, following Apple human interface guidelines touch areas are at least 44x44px which doesn't mean you need to create a large icon - like the navigation buttons visible area height is below the recommended, the touchable area is still 44px high. You could try to adopt the cells to HIG, will probably help you to find an issue.

Comment: @A-Live I've tried making it bigger but still no dice. Only the same small portion of it on the right is clickable. Again, it works in all the other cells just not in the first row of one of the table views. This icon is in a table row and is about as big as a disclosure icon or others you'd see in a table cell.

Comment: @MishieMoo That's a great idea, I didn't even know about that ability. I just tried it and the images are in the right spots with a box around the complete image...

Comment: @MishieMoo I also updated my question with the code you requested.

Comment: You don't need to post `loadChildren` code as you are saying it isn't called, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would be helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: @A-Live I've update the question with a more complete `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I didn't want to post it because it's so long but here's is a scaled down version that still exhibits the problem. Let me know if you have any ideas

Comment: @ragamufin now that's something to play with, will keep you posted.

Comment: @ragamufin your code works just as expected for me, but i can't find the place where the `Yesterday` label is added, are you making any changes to cell at superclass `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: I stripped down the code I posted for you so that all the other dependencies weren't there while still producing the problem. My normal `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is probably 3 times more code and just confuses the issue. The superclasses have different datasources for a very similar table so all they are doing in their `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is figuring out whether or not they should display a `noTasks` cell or `rowCell`. Does that make sense? They are both literally 4 or 5 lines of code.

Comment: So I managed to figure this out and wanted to report back. Thanks for all your help on this but it was a bit of a wild goose chase for you. I have a view that slides in from the left of the screen, similar to the Facebook sidebar. I'm not sure how it was doing it but after debugging for a while I figured out that the header of that sidebar was somehow interfering with the first row of my table. I simply moved the sidebar a little further offscreen and voila! problem solved. Thanks again for trying, I upvoted your comments @A-Live.

Comment: @ragamufin glad you did it :) please leave some details as an answer and accept it for the future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone runs into a similar issue as rare as that may be maybe this will help avoid someone going bald pulling their hair out. So my problem wasn't with the tableView itself but a sidebar I have that is similar to the facebook sidebar that slides in and out. My sidebar has a tableview in it and that table has a header on it that for some reason when it was right beside my other table was somehow preventing clicks to the image in that first row. My solution was simply to position that sidebar view a little bit further offscreen away from the view it was beside instead of being right next to it. Problem solved. Thanks to all who tried to help me out.